# ALSA: Opening and closing PCM On-The-Fly

Tags: c, linux, audio, alsa

I have a program that does the following:

1. Opens the default PCM with **snd_pcm_open()** function
2. Sends samples to play a sound
3. Closes the PCM with **snd_pcm_close()** function

The program will periodically play any sound requests it receives, but occasionally the open will fail and return a "Device or resource busy" error. This typically happens when there are a lot of sound files. However, the close call is always successful. I would assume that if the close was successful that the PCM would be immediately available for anyone else to use. I should also add that there is nothing else on the system using sound.

Could it be possible that ALSA still needs to clean up some resources after the close? Is the PCM interface not designed to be opened and closed that often? Most examples on the Internet open the PCM stream at start up and close it at shut down.

Answer (score 4):

Do not close and open this often. You could use

`snd_pcm_open()` and `snd_pcm_close()` only once (start and end of your application) and use this when you want to reset your streams:

```
snd_pcm_drop()
```

and

```
snd_pcm_prepare()
```

Normally this shouldn't be a problem at all, since dmix can handle several streams. However, if you're using direct hw:0 access, the close() step might be asynchronous in some way, that an immediate open() might not work too well.

Comment: Closing the the pcm seems to be the only way that I can generate a SND_SOC_DAPM_PRE_PMD widget event in DAPM core (my motivation is power saving). Is there another way to trigger this through alsa-lib?

Comment: @Maister: Then how can we manage changing sampling rate in stream? For example I have 2 streams of PCM with 44.1 KHz and  48KHz Sampling rates and I want to output this audio s (ie, some time 44.1 and some time 48). I think during this switching Alsa close and open is needed. Is there is any other method for that?

Comment: @jjm No, it should be enough to simply call snd_pcm_drain() to play all pending frames with old sampling rate and then setting new parameters for pcm which would contain changed sampling rate.

Comment: @waffleman Did you find a solution to avoid to open/close the pcm on each usage ? I have the same issue. If I keep the pcm open during all the life code, the power saving is awful. I try the pause or suspend alsa function without more success.